# QGIS: Transform or reproject XYZ into BBOX

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, wmts, ogc-api-features

I'm new to the QGIS so the question may be easy to solve but I'm coming from the Mapserver environment, which is a bit different.

Is there a way how QGIS could transform or reproject the WMTS tilerow, tilecol and tilematrix into the bbox?

Mapserver does this automatically when the layer is using the OAPIF as a source. And I'm wondering if QGIS can do the same.

Our architecture:

We are running OGC Features API compatible backend server. On input, it expects to receive BBOX query param to be able to filter the available features.

Then, we've got the **QGIS server** running in docker with a single layer attached to the OGC Features API backend (basically as a source of data)

Our front-end application fires a WMTS request to the QGIS server hosted in docker. The url has the following form:
`http://localhost:8030/?map=/etc/qgisserver/project.qgs&SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetTile&VERSION=1.0.0&layer=ourLayer&FORMAT=image/png&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:3857&TILEMATRIX=15&TILEROW=21424&TILECOL=14008`

Brief illustration of the architecture:

**(Front-End APP)** ----WMTS-----> **(QGIS Server)** ----OGC Features API---> **(OAPIF Backend)**

The problem is that when the request eventually reaches the OAPIF backend, there's no BBOX available.

Is there a way to enable the "transformation" of XYZ into BBOX between QGIS Server and OAPIF Backend?